# LinkedList getFirstElement and getLastElement Methods

Tags: java, interface, linked-list, inner-classes

I need to write a Java program (class LinkedList) that should do all the stuff without using import List and I have tried but I am not sure from if they are working or not.

Can someone please help me? Especially getFirstElement and getLastElement methods.

Here are my classes:

```
package main.java.a3;

public interface List<E> {
    public void add(E e); 
    public void add(int index, E e);
    public int size();
    public E get(int index);
    public boolean isEmpty();
}




package main.java.a3;

    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    public class LinkedList<E> implements List<E>{

        private ListNode head;

        @Override
        public void add(E e) {
            if(e == null){
                throw new NullPointerException("Element was null");
            }   
            if(head == null){
                head = new ListNode(e,null);
            }else{  
                    ListNode temp = head;
                    while(temp.next!=null){
                        temp=temp.next;
                    }
                    temp.setNext(new ListNode(e,null));
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void add(int index, E e) {
            if(e == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Element was null!");
            }
            else if(index<0){
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index was negative");
            }
            else if(index>=size() + 1){
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index was bigger than size");  
            } else {
                ListNode temp = head;
                while(temp.next != null) {
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                temp.setNext(new ListNode(e, null));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            int size = 0;
            ListNode temp = head;
            while(temp != null) {
                size++;
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }  
               return size;
        }

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            if(index<0){
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index was negative");
            }
            if(index>=size()){
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index was bigger than size");  
            }
            ListNode temp = head;
            for (int i = 0; i<index;i++){
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            return temp.data;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            if(head == null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

                // innere Klasse        
                        private class ListNode{
                            E data;
                            ListNode next;

                            public ListNode(E data, ListNode next){
                                setData(data);
                                setNext(next);
                            }

                            public void setData(E data){
                                this.data = data;
                            }

                            public void setNext(ListNode next){
                                this.next = next;
                            }

                            public E getData() {
                                return data;
                            }

                            public ListNode getNext() {
                                return next;
                            }

                        }
                // innere Klasse    

        public String toString() {
                return head.toString(); 
        }

        public void addFirst(E elem) {
            if(elem == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Element was null!");
            } else {
                ListNode temp = new ListNode(elem, head);
                if(head != null) {
                    temp.setNext(head);
                }
                head = temp;
            }
        }

        public void addLast(E elem) {
            if(elem == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Element was null!");
            } else {
                ListNode tail = new ListNode(elem, null);
                while(head != null) {
                    tail.getNext();
                    if(tail.getNext() == null) {
                        tail.setNext(head);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        public E getFirst() {
            if(head == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Element was null!");
            }else {
                return (E) head;
            }

        }

        public E getLast(){
            E elem = null;
            ListNode tail = new ListNode(elem, null);
            if(tail == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Element was null!");
            }
            return (E) tail;
        }


    }
```

Comment: getFirstElement should be simply `return head.getData()`

Comment: getLastElement is `if (head.getNext() == null){return data;} else {return getNext().getLastElement();}` Where next().getLastElement is a recursive call.

Comment: getFirst method is working, but getLast is not working. but thank you anyway.

Comment: Was just writing an edit, but an error occured;

getLastElement is `if (head.getNext() == null){return data;} else {return getNext().getLastElement();}` Where next().getLastElement is a recursive call.

Comment: getLast should be the same logic as your addLast function except you don't add a new node, but you return the last node that is not null

Comment: You don't need import in java, just use full name, for example java.util.LinkedList, profit. Good professor will accept.

Comment: @Whatzs Our professor would probably not even evaluate your performance if you did that.

Comment: it is still not working. No i cant not use java.util because the point of this is getting the generics but i can not get it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getFirstElement() and getLastElement()

/* supposing the **elements** in your link list are **stored in** a variable **data** of the Node class */

```
public E getFirst() {
            if(head == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Element was null!");
            }else {
                return (E) head.data;
            }

        }

        public E getLast(){
            if(head == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Element was null!");
            }
            else{
                for(Node iterate=head; iterate!=null; iterate=iterate.next){
                    return (E) iterate.data;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getFirst` you are casting `head` element to `E` and `head` is of type `ListNode`. You need to return `head.data`, not `head` itself. That is if you actually want the value, not the element, if you want the element then just return `head` and change return type to `ListNode`.

I don't understand your `getLast` tho, you are making a new element, then checking if it's null (?) and then again casting it to `E` when it's `ListNode`. You need to iterate your whole list to get to the last element, and then return it, something like:

```java
ListNode temp = head;
while(temp.next != null)
  temp = temp.next;
return temp.data;
```

Then like I wrote before, you can return either element or the value. Ofcourse you need to take care of possible nullpointers, like `head` being null etc., but you know that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, the iterative one and the constant-time option.

In the **Iterative** you have a head pointing to the first node, so getting first element is just to call the head.data(), but for the last element you must iterate with a while/for loop until currentNode.next()!=null

In the **Constant-time** option, you have two pointers, one for head, other for last element. For getting the first element it's the same than the iterative way, but for getting the last one, you must use the *last* pointer to return the value.  The complex thing here is to have the control about adding/removing elements to update de *last* node.

A very basic example could be:

```
public class LinkedList<E> implements List<E>{
    private ListNode<E> head;
    private ListNode<E> last;
    private int size;

    public E getFirst(){
        if(head!=null)
            return head.data();
        else
            return null;
    }

    public E getIterativeLast(){
        if(head!=null){
            ListNode<E> last =  head;
            for(;last.next()!=null; last=last.next());
            return last.data(());

        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }


    public E getConstantLast(){
        if(last != null){
            return last.data();
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void add(E elem){
        LastNode<E> newElem = new LastNode(elem);
        if(head == null){
            head = last = newElem;
        }else{
            last.setNext(newElem);
            last = newElem:
        }
        size++;
    }

}
```

"Graphically" could be like:

```
head ---> n1|->n2|->null
               /
last ---------/


head ---> n1|->n2|->n3->null
                    /
last --------------/
```